# Cordova iOS build white screen

Tags: cordova, uiwebview, reactjs, browserify, hybrid

Note: my issue does not relate to the splashscreen issue

So I've been having a bit of a headache the past few days trying to figure out why my browserify + react app won't load in an iOS webview built by Cordova. The app works perfectly fine on Android, but on iOS, after displaying the Cordova load screen it just stays blank. It appears that my built script (build.js) isn't really doing much at all. console.log doesn't do anything in the safari webview inspector, and React.render doesn't seem to be called.

This is my main.js file (source for build.js)

```
var React   = require('react'),
    Router  = require('./components/router');

var $ = require('jquery');

var injectTapEventPlugin = require("react-tap-event-plugin");

var css = require('./node_modules/react-star-rating-input/src/css');

var insertCss = require('insert-css');


console.log("main.js loaded, app not rendered yet");

function onDeviceReady() {

  console.log("App running!");

  //Needed for onTouchTap
  //Can go away when react 1.0 release
  //Check this repo:
  //https://github.com/zilverline/react-tap-event-plugin

  injectTapEventPlugin();

  insertCss(css);

  Router.run(function (Handler) {
    React.render(
      React.createElement(Handler, null),
      document.body
    );
  });
};

onDeviceReady();

$(document).ready(function() {
  document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
}.bind(onDeviceReady));
```

Note that the onDeviceReady call is just for browser testing, this will be removed at a later stage.

I'm running the app in an iPhone 6 simulator (iOS 8.4) and I'm using Cordova 4.1.2.

I hope someone out there can help me! Thanks in advance.

Comment: use safari remote inspector to see if you are getting some js error

Answer (score 0):

The problem is most probably in your Router definition. You should not use "Router.HistoryLocation"
https://github.com/rackt/react-router/issues/310

Try like this without `Router.HistoryLocation`:

```js
Router.run(routes, function (Handler) {
  React.render(<Handler />, document.getElementById('app'));
});
```